# Firebase SDK conflict with google sign-in SDk in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-signin, conflict

### can anybody help to fix this Error?

**After Force Resolve, this error shows up** =>

Unable to copy Assets\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.srcaar to Assets\GeneratedLocalRepo\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.aar.  Assets\GeneratedLocalRepo\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.aar will not be included in Gradle builds. Reason: Failed to copy Assets\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.srcaar to Assets\GeneratedLocalRepo\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.aar due to System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "Assets\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.srcaar" or "Assets\GeneratedLocalRepo\GoogleSignIn\Editor\m2repository\com\google\signin\google-signin-support\1.0.4\google-signin-support-1.0.4.aar"
at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00192] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0
at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) [0x00000] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0
at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.CopyAssetAndLabel (System.String sourceLocation, System.String targetLocation, System.Boolean force) [0x0009e] in /Users/chkuang/Workspace/git/unity-jar-resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:2467

Resolution Failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Close and open Unity.
Turn off and on the pc.
Check that file in the given path is present.
If there is, delete it and re-import that file.
If you don't solve, delete all assets linked to google sign in and import again the plugin.
If you do not solve it, directly delete all the Firebase assets and reimport them, perhaps updated to the latest version.
If that doesn't work, delete the cache folder in library and go back to Unity.
If it doesn't work, delete gradle from its folder (it depends on the operating system).

These problems are the worst to solve because it is often very complicated to understand what specifically is wrong.
I've listed the options I would do for you.

If I have been helping you, you can accept my answer to thank me :).
good work!

Comment: Thank you for replying to me, I still have the same error even after trying to remove SDK for google sign-in and firebase auth and reimport it with no result, I also tried closing unity and opening it again end even restart windows with no result to solve this error.

Comment: In the end, I started a new project and I import these packages then I import my project files then I build the project after succeeding in resolving it, and it works in the new project.